# What is the correct way to load a collection of a reference of an object in EF Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Take the following:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ClassB> ClassBs { get; set; }
    public bool ChangeMe { get; set; }
}

public class ClassB
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string test { get; set; }
    public bool bar { get; set; }
    public ClassA ClassA { get; set; }
    public int ClassAID { get; set; }
}
```

I have a ClassB Object loaded and I want to run some code that does a few things, and then changes bar to true.

After I have done this, if every ClassB in the Class A's ClassBs collection has a true, I want to change ClassA's ChangeMe to true.

So, if I have a single ClassB loaded to an object called `bla`, I would try the following:

```
if (bla.ClassA.ClassBs.Where(x => x.bar == false).Count() == 0)
{
    Do Something
}
```

However, despite having loads of ClassB objects that should be loaded, the only one that I have according to locals is the current, and it seems to enact the `Do Something` unexpectedly.

I have tried the following:

```
_context.Entry(bla).Reference(x => x.ClassA).Load()
_context.Entry(bla).Collection(x => x.ClassA.ClassBs).Load()
_context.Entry(bla.ClassA).Collection(x => x.ClassBs).Load()
```

And a few more, but, I seem to get various different exceptions.

Short of simply loading another object and calling `.Include()` in the normal way, is there anyway of achieving what I am trying to do?

Comment: What are the exceptions you are getting? The docs are specifying Entry().Collection().Load() as the way for explicit loading of collection navigation properties.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can (1) use [Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.referenceentry-2.query?view=efcore-2.1) method (available for both reference and collection navigation properties) and (2) combine it with eager loading methods (`Include` / `ThenInclude`), e.g.

```
_context.Entry(bla).Reference(x => x.ClassA)
    .Query() // <-- (1)
    .Include(x => x.ClassBs) // <-- (2)
    .Load();
```

Answer (score 0):

First I think you should mark your navigation properties as `virtual`

```
 public class ClassA
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ClassB> ClassBs { get; set; }
    public bool ChangeMe { get; set; }
}

public class ClassB
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string test { get; set; }
    public bool bar { get; set; }
    public virtual ClassA ClassA { get; set; }
    public int ClassAID { get; set; }
}
```

and then use a chain of `Include` and `ThenInclude`

```
    var bla = _context.Set<ClassB>().Include(cb=>cb.ClassA).ThenInclude(ca=>ca.ClassBs).ThenInclude(cb=>cb.ClassA).Where(x=>x.Id=blaId)
if (bla.ClassA.ClassBs.Where(x => x.bar == false).Count() == 0)
{
   Do Something
}
```

Comment: navigation properties do not need to be virtual if you are going to use eager loading anyways...